# Json attribute is getting truncated in request body (Pojo class) in spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need a help on Json string (base 64) is getting truncated in request body where as it is working as expected in first http request and getting failed in 2nd http request onwards.

```
public class Base64Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        String value = "";
        try {
            JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
            value = node.asText();
            System.out.println("in deserialize() :" + value);
            //ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("in deserialize() :: Exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here value is having complete base64 string in first http request but got truncated value in 2nd request on wards.

total length of base 64 string is more than 34K.

Please let me know what I can do to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: The *same* string gets truncated on second request, or a different one?

Comment: can you reproduce it with a string size 100?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Its getting reproduced with same string in 2nd http request.

Comment: @efekctive it is reproducing for large string value only, let says more than 30K length

Comment: Have you inspected the payloads after the first request?

Comment: @efekctive same payload, no change. one more thing, same code is working fine with local host but getting failed in linux VM machine.

Comment: If it works locally and fails on a VM, my instinct is that it's likely to do with how the VM is configured

Comment: I introduced 5 sec delay in my filter class then it is working fine but still need to find the root cause and solution for this.

Comment: I am sure you are using the same string. I have doubts about what is actually sent over to the VM or accepted by the VM